# Download Qt sdk on windows-32 bit system: which one to choose between MinGW 4.7, VS 2010, VS 2010 OpenGL?

Tags: windows, qt, sdk, download

I would like to download **Qt sdk** (libraries+ IDE Qt Creator). 
I'm on a win-32 system but there is 3 choices for Windows 32-bit system :

- Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (**MinGW 4.7**, 650 MB)
- Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (**VS 2010**, 485 MB)
- Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (**VS 2010, OpenGL**, 476 MB)

What are the differences between them and which one to choose for having Qt sdk on a win-32 system ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your compiler.

Use

- *MinGW 4.7* if your compiler is **MinGW 4.7**
- *VS 2010* if you're on **visual studio 10** compiler

The decision what binaries you download is the decision what compiler you'll use too.

If you are not sure or use another one, better you download the sourcecode of qt and compile your own.

Here's how to do so:

- [Building Qt Desktop for Windows with MinGW](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MinGW)
- [Building Qt Desktop for Windows with MSVC](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC)

***Hint:*** realy make shure you use the mingw version mentioned in the documentation, else you can get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962857/qt-application-segmentation-fault-with-mingw-4-7-2) problem.

Comment: Thks, it's more clear in my head. I have already downloaded Microsoft Visual c# 2010 Express before, so is there a link with the visual studio 10 compiler ?

Comment: You need a VSC++ compiler - not sure if that is part of V#2010 express.

Comment: Okey thks, i'll experiment and test all that !

Comment: Would you please post your experiment result?